# Passing Values into a function

Tags: python

Here is the function I wish to use to calculate a distance via lat/long

```
def calculateDistance( latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ):
    from decimal import Decimal
    latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo = [Decimal(x) for x in (latOne, lonOne, latTwo,lonTwo)]
    DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
    coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
    alpha = 90 - latTwo
    beta  = 90 - latOne

    cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
    cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
    sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
    sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
    cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

    cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
    cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
    cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
    angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
    distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
    return distance
```

if I have a set of lats and long in lists, for example:

```
lat = ['200', '210', '240', '300'] 
long = ['10', '20', '30', '40']
```

and a known coordinate for `latOne`, `lonOne`, which equals

```
lat = 100 
lon = 200
```

Is there a way I can loop over the lists and apply them to the function? Essentially, I want to set `latOne` and `lonOne` always equal to the known coordinates and then loop over the lists and supply these values in the list to `latTwo` and `lonTwo` for all values in the list.

Simply put, is there a way to pass the values to the function and then return the distance and redo this for all lat and long values?

For example:

```
latOne =100, lonOne = 200, latTwo = 200, lonOne = 10 
to function then return distance.
then run 
latOne =100, lonOne = 200, latTwo = 210, lonOne = 20
```

and so on until all the list values for long and lat are input to the function.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you want to do. Do you wan't to call the function for every "pair" of lat and lon ? e.g. passing 200 and 10 to the function. next passing 210 and 20 to the function and so on ? Why even use parameters for lonOne and latOne if they never change ?

Comment: @pypat yes that is exactly what i would like to do. I want to pass every pair like you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like:

```
results = [CalculateDistance(100,200,lattwo,lontwo) 
           for lattwo,lontwo in zip(latOne,lonOne)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's `zip` function combines two [lists into a list of tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). You can iterate over it to get each pair one at a time:

```
for latTwo, lonTwo in zip(lat, long):
  print calculateDistance(latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo )
```

The above just prints the result. You can generate the array the old fashioned way:

```
out=[]
for latTwo, lonTwo in zip(lat, long):
  out.append(calculateDistance(latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ))
```

Or you can use list comprehensions:

```
 [calculateDistance(latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ) for latTwo, lonTwo in zip(lat, long)]
```

Comment: awesome thanks. I was trying to initialize both lists simillar to this by calling both list variables but this makes much more sense

Comment: You can also take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial to create a function where latOne and lonOne will always be the same. It's worth a read :)